# Django model field has null=True but yields IntegrityError even after database is reset

Tags: django, django-models

I've seen many questions posed by users struggling with django errors of the form:

> IntegrityError at... null value in column X violates not-null constraint

Usually this is because they've updated their `models.py` with `null=True, blank=True` only after the original `syncdb` operation and they need to manually update the SQL table in question or else migrate using south.  However, I am having exactly this problem despite having dropped the database schema entirely and rebuilt it using `syncdb` with the correct options in `models.py`.  Can anybody explain this?  Obviously I can just update the column in Postgre to remove NOT NULL, but I am concerned that this is happening at all.

`models.py`:

```
class TopTen(models.Model):
    toptenuser = models.ForeignKey(TopTenUser)
    date_in = models.DateTimeField()
    date_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

`syncdb`:

```
> (venv)richard@ubuntu:~/DjangoProjects/Heroku/mytopten$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
> Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.5406
> Creating tables ...
> Creating table auth_permission
> Creating table auth_group_permissions
> Creating table auth_group
> Creating table auth_user_groups
> Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
> Creating table auth_user
> Creating table django_content_type
> Creating table django_session
> Creating table django_site
> Creating table django_admin_log
> Creating table mytopten_toptenuser
> Creating table mytopten_topten
> Creating table mytopten_song_toptens
> Creating table mytopten_song
```

And yet the first time I do `runserver` and try to enter a TopTen instance:

> IntegrityError: null value in column "date_out" violates not-null constraint

Am I doing something wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: can you verify in the database that `mysql` has `date_out` as  a nullable field?

Comment: straight after the syncdb, `SELECT is_nullable FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name='date_out';` yields "NO".  I can just change this with ALTER COLUMN and the whole app then works fine, I just can't work out why Django is setting it to "NOT NULL" in the first place.

Comment: you are doing everything fine. may be it was just a caching issue - with the pyc of the models still not having the updated nullable fields before doing the syncdb again.

Comment: Sorry, I should also specify that the database is PostgreSQL. Thanks.

Comment: You are totally correct, karthikr, I am simply too impatient.  Having run everything again, it now works fine and the column is nullable by default, so I assume it was the cached models.pyc.  Thanks for the help.